# Can I refresh Windows 8.1 with Windows 8 media?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8-refresh

I bought an **Windows 8 Upgrade License** after it was released (April, 2012) and installed it in my computer. When Windows 8.1 was released, I received it through Windows Update.
Now I'm facing the **Black Screen of Death** after Login. I need to perform a Refresh (without losing my files) and it asks for a Bootable Media.

- **The files** I still have are from 2012 and I tried to put it in a **Flash Drive and Refresh from it**, but Windows says it's not a **valid media**.
- If I **boot** said Flash Drive and try to perform a Refresh on Windows, **it says the drive is locked** (because it was booted from USB rather than C:).

Now I'm wondering:

- If I download Windows 8.0 media from Microsoft Website and try to refresh Windows 8.1, will it work or will it be incompatible?
- Can I use a Windows 8.1 media installer from another person to refresh my computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No;  You cannot;**

`Windows 8` and `Windows 8.1` kernel is different.  Sadly Microsoft never communicated this and does not actually ever offer you a chance to create an .ISO of `Windows 8.1` when the update is installed.

This means the installation disk you have won't allow you to refresh your computer.  You will need a Windows 8.1 installation disk of the same type as your current installation to Refresh/Reset your computer.

Its also a good idea to update the Refresh image itself once you have your system in a state you want it.  You should store this image on the system disk and on another disk as a backup.

Comment: After reading your answer I decided to download a "clean" windows 8.1 ISO from the pirate bay (without crack or key gen) and used Rufus.exe to create a bootable USB ISO. It worked perfectly. My original key is still in use since I didn't use the downloaded ISO for a clean install.

Comment: That is very good news.